# Nav bar wont remain fixed

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, nav

Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top not working
I dont have any other styling applied to the nav
I have tried adding a high z-indxs to the nav element and a lower one to the body but still no joy?

```
    <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid kaki">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Quinta Dos Brejos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="local amenities\local.html" target="_blank">Places of interest</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../GettingAround/GettingAround.html" target="_blank">Getting Around</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../Gallery/Gallery.html" target="_blank">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.thealgarvetraveller.com" target="_blank">Transfers/Tours</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sample code?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light static-top">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider">
                </div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
       Search
      </button>
          </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider">
                </div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>
          Hello, world!
        </h2>
        <p>
          Now your navbar is fixed
        </p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks however I commented out my nav bar used above code including scripts and its still the same